# go get wails is not installing properly

Tags: vue.js, go

Trying to use...  golang and wails...   but after this...

`go get github.com/wailsapp/wails/cmd/wails`

I am getting this.

```
   ../../github.com/wailsapp/wails/cmd/semver.go:21:3: cannot use semverVersion (type semver.Version) as type *semver.Version in field value
../../github.com/wailsapp/wails/cmd/semver.go:48:40: cannot use s.Version (type *semver.Version) as type semver.Version in argument to constraint.Validate
../../github.com/wailsapp/wails/cmd/semver.go:64:40: cannot use s.Version (type *semver.Version) as type semver.Version in argument to constraint.Validate
../../github.com/wailsapp/wails/cmd/semver.go:91:35: cannot use c[j].Version (type *semver.Version) as type semver.Version in argument to c[i].Version.LessThan
```

and
`wails init`   also not working.

The latest versions of get and golang installed.

any sugestions?

Comment: The wails app was broken by [a change](https://github.com/Masterminds/semver/commit/23f51de38a0866c5ef0bfc42b3f735c73107b700) to `github.com/masterminds/semver`.

Comment: So I should wait for this to be fixed?  I am assuming

Comment: You can wait for a fix or checkout an older version of github.com/masterminds/semver.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your shell file has:

```sh
export GO111MODULE=on
export PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

`go get github.com/wailsapp/wails/cmd/wails` was indeed broken by a change in Masterminds/semver, however the official way to install Wails is to ensure you have `GO111MODULE=on` before installing. This generally will safeguard you from this issue.

Comment: This didn't for me. The command is still not being installed.

Comment: Check your PATH has the `go/bin` directory in it.